# Postgresql Convert Json Object to Columns

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql database. I have a column which is **jsonb data type**.
For example I have a json data like below:

```
{
"test_question_number": ["1000000000", "5000000000"],
"question1": 0.04975124378109453,
"question2": 5.077114427860696,
"question3": 75621.89054726369,
"question4": 3482.587064676617,
"question6": 1,
"question8": 0.000176068
}
```

As you see it is key value json data. And the data can be different, So the key names are not same for other saved json data.

Now I would like to convert it as colum and row. Like below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   |test_question_number  |question1|           |question2|         |question3| 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |   "1000000000"       | 0.04975124378109453| 5.077114427860696  |75621.89054726369
------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 |   "5000000000"       |                    |                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried jsonb_build_object, jsonb_populate_recordset and some function but I could not solve.

Comment: How do you know that `question1`field refers to the first element of `test_question_number`?

Comment: I did not know what you mean. It is a json data  and it is sequential

Comment: It's not a valid json because of `"test_question_number": {"1000000000", "5000000000"},` - it would be valid with `["1000000000", "5000000000"]`. You can validate the example i.e. with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes, thanks for correction. I will edit question.

Comment: The format still doesn't support your intended use: if the value of ```test_question_number``` element is an array then why for instance isn't the value of ```question1``` element also an array, i.e. ```[0.04975124378109453, 0.0]```?  If it were, a dynamic solution would likely be possible.

Answer (score 0):

A static pivoting solution might be

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT JSONB_TYPEOF(value::JSONB) AS type, js.*
    FROM t
   CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH(jsdata) AS js
)
SELECT arr.*, question1, question2, question3, question4, question6, question8
  FROM
  (
   SELECT row_id, test_question_number 
     FROM t
    CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(value::JSONB) 
     WITH ORDINALITY arr(test_question_number,row_id)
    WHERE type = 'array' ) AS arr
  LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT cnt, MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question1') AS question1,
                MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question2') AS question2,
                MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question3') AS question3,
                MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question4') AS question4,
                MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question6') AS question6,
                MAX(value::text) FILTER (WHERE key = 'question8') AS question8
      FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY key) AS cnt
              FROM t
             WHERE type != 'array' 
           ) AS q
     GROUP BY cnt ) AS obj
         ON arr.row_id = obj.cnt
```

distinguishing the elements by types as JSON objects whether an `array` or `non-array`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=469b731c88bacc65ad29b74130e7d419)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, but this is not that I am looking for. I need a dynamic solution.

Comment: you're welcome @Emrullah , but it's very hard to convert to a dynamic one, even through some type of functions returning `record` or `refcursor`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's jsonb format seems odd if one were designing this workflow from scratch and expecting a dynamic solution. However, a more concise static solution is possible than the one submitted below. Partial example query:

```
with tbl1 as (
  select json_array_elements_text((jsdata->>'test_question_number')::json) 
  as test_question_number from jstable
), tbl2 as (
  select jsrecord.* from jstable, jsonb_to_record(jsdata) 
  as jsrecord(question1 text, question2 text, question3 text)
) 
select x.test_question_number, y.question1, y.question2, y.question3 
from (select row_number() over() as rn, * from tbl1) x
left join (select row_number() over() as rn, * from tbl2) y using (rn);
```

Returns this output:

[image: output of query]